# Rails can't understand association when querying using activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a models, `Task`, `Taskable` & `Supply`. They have this associations relationship.

```
class Task < AR::Base
  has_one :taskable, inverse_of: :task, autosave: true
  enum status: { :awaiting, :restarting, ... }

class Taskable < AR::Base
  belongs_to :task, inverse_of: :taskable, autosave: true
  has_many :supplies

class Supply < AR::Base
  belongs_to :taskable
```

I need to find supplies, which are connected to tasks with some enum value. Here's how I construct a query:

```
Supply.where(
  taskable: {
    task: {
      status: [ :awaiting, :starting ]
    }
  })
```

But I catch an exception:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "taskable"
LINE 1: ...upplies" WHERE "supplies"."component_id" = $1 AND "taskable"...
: SELECT  "supplies".* FROM "supplies" WHERE "supplies"."component_id" =  $1 AND "taskable"."task_id" = '---
:status:
- :awaiting
- :starting
'  ORDER BY "supplies"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "taskable"
LINE 1: ...upplies" WHERE "supplies"."component_id" = $1 AND "taskable"...                                                             ^
: SELECT  "supplies".* FROM "supplies" WHERE "supplies"."component_id" = $1 AND "taskable"."task_id" = '---
:status:
- :awaiting
- :starting
'  ORDER BY "supplies"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

How can I query exactly what I want w/o exceptions?

**UPDATED**

`db/schema.rb`

```
create_table "tasks", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  t.integer  "responsible_id",  null: false
  t.integer  "status",          null: false
end

create_table "taskables", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "task_id",    null: false
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "supplies", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "taskable_id",  null: false
  t.datetime "expired_at"
  t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
end
```

Comment: I believe you need to use the numeric values of your enum in ```where``` queries. ```Task.statuses("awaiting")``` IIRC. I may be wrong though - I jumped on Rails 4 before enums were available and got locked in by RailsAdmin, so I don't have direct experience.

Comment: Can you also add your database schema for these objects?

Comment: I've add my `db/schema.rb` code. Also, I've updated my models (I forgot to write about inverse of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know `where` cannot go deep through relations.
What it should look like from my point of view is:

```
class Task < AR::Base
  has_one :taskable, inverse_of: :task, autosave: true
  enum status: { :awaiting, :restarting, ... }
class Taskable < AR::Base
  belongs_to :task, inverse_of: :taskable, autosave: true
  has_many :supplies
class Supply < AR::Base
  belongs_to :taskable
  has_many :supplies, through: :taskable
```

And to get what you want you'll be able to use:
`Supply.joins(:tasks).where(tasks: {status: [:awaiting, :starting]})`

Also pay attention to status values in `where` clause. If you are using rails 4.1 you'll have to pass numeric values of statuses.

**UPDATED**

Or the simpler way without `has_many :through`

`Supply.joins(taskable: :tasks).where(tasks: {status: [:awaiting, :starting]})`

Comment: I'm rails `4.2` user. Should I pass numeric values?

Comment: Then it should be ok to use names for enum. Still you can easily check it by looking at `Task.where(status: :awaiting).to_sql`. If it will have `"status" = NULL` in the end, you should pass numeric values :)
As I can see this ability was added in 4.2.3 version and 4.2.2 don't have it http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: where are you? Please approve my edit, I'll accept your answer

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to approve due to rating amount. Added your edit as my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the `PG::UndefinedTable` error because when querying on where-clauses on associations, you need to specify the table names, and not the association name.

This might give you a better result:

```
Supply.where(
  taskables: {
    tasks: { 
      status: [:awaiting, :starting]
    }
  }
)
```

You might also have to include or join in the actual associations, depending on whether you only want the join query, or if you are looking to preload the associations. Use `.includes` for preloading, and `.joins` for just the join query.

```
Supply.includes(taskable: :task).where(...)
```

or

```
Supply.joins(taskable: :task).where(...)
```

EDIT: thanks @Pavling for mentioning the difference between `.joins` and `.includes`.

Comment: I'd suggest `.joins` rather that `.includes` - if you're interested in the query join but not on a preload

Comment: That is a very good point. I actually mention "include or join" in my answer, so I should probably clarify that you can use `.joins` instead, and why that should be considered. Thank you.

Comment: Just copy pasted your answer. `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column taskables.tasks does not exist`

Comment: Ah, of course. Have a look at @Glupo's answer, in that case, or simply do `Supply.joins(:taskable: :task).where(tasks: { status: :awaiting, :starting] })`. That might work better.